# flip-card doesn't freeze after a click

Tags: jquery, css, flip

So i have some cards with the flip effect on hover, once we are looking the back on the card i want it to stay there as the checkbox on the back stays checked, I tried with JS but it didn't work

here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/9xw2860r/50/

```
$('.flip').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});

$('.checkbox1').click(function() {
  $(".card").addClass('flipped');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hover leave will remove the class you add on click. You could do a check if the checkbox is checked then do not remove the class `flipped` on leave

https://jsfiddle.net/9xw2860r/51/

```
$('.flip').hover(function() {
  var $card = $(this).find('.card');
  var $checkbox = $(this).find('.checkbox');

  if (!$card.hasClass('flipped')) {
    $card.addClass('flipped');
  } else if ($card.hasClass('flipped') && !$checkbox.prop('checked')) {
    $card.removeClass('flipped');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, is that you assigned the `class="checkbox1"` to the parent `<div>`, instead of the actual `<input />` element.

Also, having listened out for the `click` event, you must check if the checkbox is checked:

```
$('.checkbox1').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $(".card").addClass('flipped');
    }
    else {
        $(".card").removeClass('flipped');
    }
});
```

You don't need the hover event handler in JQuery either. Instead, the hover effect can be achieved in CSS by adding the selector:

```
.flip:hover .card {
   -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
    transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
```

A link to the Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9xw2860r/52/).

Comment: that's great! thank you, but now what if i have more than one card like this https://jsfiddle.net/9xw2860r/53/